# Accept 5 names and print the longest name?

Tags: java, compareto, string-length

I want to the longest name for 5 given names. I think I should use `compareTo()` method or `length()`?

Output must be like this :

```
enter 5 names :
Joey
Mark
Catherine
Zachery
Foster

Longest name is Catherine.
```

What method should I use and how? This is my code so far:

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = ""
System.out.print("Enter 5 names");
name = x.nextLine();
name2 = x.nextLine();
name3 = x.nextLine();
name4 = x.nextLine();
name5 = x.nextLine();

if(name.compareTo(name2)>0)  //is this method right?
```

Comment: You should use `String#length()` and a `for loop` :)

Comment: @TheLostMind and a data structure (array, list...)

Comment: @ReutSharabani - *probably yes* but its not *mandatory*. You could find the bigger of the current and last name :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani No need to stock them all if you only need the longest.

Comment: You might collect the strings into a list or array and sort it according to length.

Comment: `longest = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(name, name2, ...), Comparator.comparing(String::length))`.

Comment: The point is that storing them in `name`, `name1` ... `namen` is not a good way of storing them. It's not a good way of storing data. If you give up storing them completely than yes - no need to store them for the longest name.

Comment: Is this your school homework?

Comment: @WeareBorg -Probably. But the OP has atleast tried.

Comment: @TheLostMind : He has got the input from user, which might very well be already there, and as the post indicates, the user is told to use compareTO method, and that might be an example.

Comment: If you don't know which method to use, then check the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: @Lora (OP), you should close this question by ticking on the answer that you deem as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`.compareTo` tells you which string comes first in lexicographic order (<0 if s1 < s2, 0 if s1==s2, >0 if s1>s2)

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "def";
s1.compareTo(s2) < 0;
```

`.length()` returns the length of a string

```
s1.length()==3;
```

In your case, you need to compare based on length, so you need the latter. If it's only 5 names, you can take the first and assume it's the longest, and then read the others one by one by keeping the "longest so far" saved and comparing them as they come. After all, you only care about the longest.

If you wanted them to be sorted by length, while still keeping them all, you'd need to store them in some sort of collection (list, array), then sort it based on length.

The problem is easy enough, so I won't provide directly the code, try to grok it yourself, you can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work with any number of entries:

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = "", temp="";

while (x.hasNextLine()){
    temp = x.nextLine();
    if (temp.length() > name.length()) name = temp;
}

System.out.println("Longest is " + name);
```

You'll need to `Ctrl` + `Z` to end the inputStream on Windows

Comment: It can't work with any number, because it won't even compile? How have you tried your code?

Comment: Now it compiles. But you should also add the info about closing the input stream. Since OP seems to be very new she might not know it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
// no need to have 5 all over the code.
// Define it once to avoid "magic nubmers"
int namesCount = 5;
// fun fact: shortest name is always "". We don't have to use null
String longestName = "";
System.out.print("Enter " + nameCount + " names:");
for (int i=0; i< nameCount; i++){
    // store new name from user
    String candidate = in.readLine();
    // is this one longer than the current longest?
    if (longestName.length() < candidate.length()){
        // found a longer name
        longestName = candidate;
    }
}
System.out.println("Longest name is " + longestName);
```

This gives up storing the names, as it seems you only use the longest one anyway. It also generalizes the number of names to iterate, and most importantly the variable names are meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be a `for` loop to read 5 names and find the length for largest name. Using the `for` loop avoids the creation of 5 deterrent string variables.

If you want to use those names later you can go for `String` array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = "";
    String maxName = "";
    int maxLength = 0;

    System.out.println("enter 5 name :");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // read 5 names
        name = x.nextLine();
        if (maxLength < name.length()) { // check longest name
            maxLength = name.length();
            maxName = name;              // store in temp variable to show
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Longest name is " + maxName); // print largest name
}
```

Output:

> enter 5 name :
>   raj
>   sita
>   gita
>   mukherjee
>   rita
>   Longest name is mukherjee

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LenghtyName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        /*
         Instead of declaring 5 different String variable
         just use String array with size = 5
         */
        String[] names = new String[5];

        System.out.print("Enter 5 names :");

        names[0] = x.nextLine();
        names[1] = x.nextLine();
        names[2] = x.nextLine();
        names[4] = x.nextLine();
        names[5] = x.nextLine();

        //Assume lenthyName as empty String
        String lengthyName = "";

        /*
         Iterate over String array using for-each loop
         */
        for (String name : names) {
            /*
             -Check null to avoid NullPointerException
             -Trim the left and right blank space in name by #trim()
             -Compare current name length with lengthyName if greater 
             replace the lengthyName by current name.
             */
            if (name != null && name.trim().length() > lengthyName.length()) {
                lengthyName = name;
            }
        }

        /*
         Print length name
         */
        System.out.println("Longest name is " + lengthyName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should work:

```
public class LongestWord {

    public static String getLongestString(String[] array) {
          int maxLength = 0;
          String longestString = null;
          for (String s : array) {
              if (s.length() > maxLength) {
                  maxLength = s.length();
                  longestString = s;
              }
          } 
          return longestString;
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] toppings = {"Cheeddddddddddse", "Pepperoni", "Black Olivesddd"};
          String longestString = getLongestString(toppings);
          System.out.format("longest string: '%s'\n", longestString);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code for comparing 3 input strings by their length:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string1 , string2 , string3;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter three string names to compare");
    string1 = input.nextLine();
    string2 = input.nextLine();
    string3 = input.nextLine();

    if (string1.length()>string2.length()) {
        if (string1.length() > string3.length())
            System.out.println("String 1 has the longest length , length = "+string1.length());
    }

    if (string2.length()>string1.length()){
        if(string2.length()>string3.length())
            System.out.println("String 2 has the longest length , length = "+string2.length());
    }

    if (string3.length()>string1.length()) {
        if (string3.length() > string2.length())
            System.out.println("String 3 has the longest length , length = " + string3.length());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//SIMPLE JAVA SOLUTION
class GFG 
{
    String longest(String names[], int n)
 {
        String res="";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(res.length()<names[i].length())
            {
                res=names[i];
            }
        }
        return res;
        
    }
}
```